# Can't import qnx.fuse

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook

I'm creating a BlackBerry app for PlayBook using Adobe Flash Builder. For that I need to import `qnx.fuse.*` and it shows an error message telling **The import fuse could not be found**. But I can import some other BlackBerry components. For example, I have the following imports:

```
import qnx.dialog.DialogButtonProperty;
import qnx.dialog.PromptDialog;
import qnx.display.IowWindow;
import qnx.fuse.ui.buttons.LabelButton;
import qnx.fuse.ui.text.Label;
```

But, only the last two imports show errors. Why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The new Fuse components are the correct ones to use for AIR development at Playbook.

The API is documented at https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/air/api

Maybe you can't **import qnx.fuse.*;** because there are no classes in that folder, it just holds other sub-folders. It's ok.

Comment: No, as I have said, I only used the .* part to give the general idea. What I'm really trying to import is : `import qnx.fuse.ui.buttons.LabelButton;` and `import qnx.fuse.ui.text.Label;`

Comment: Right-click on your project - Properties - Flex Build Path. Do you have qnx-air.swc and qnx-screen.swc (or later: qnxui.swc) there?

Answer (score 0):

What Blackberry Playbook sdk version for air you have installed.

```
import qnx.fuse.ui.buttons.LabelButton;
import qnx.fuse.ui.text.Label;
```

These imports can be used if you are using Flashbuilder 4.6 & Air version 3.1 , below it will not supported.

```
https://developer.blackberry.com/air/apis/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things to get access to those classes.

- [Add the native extension QNXSkins from qnx](http://developer.blackberry.com/air/documentation/bb10/add_ane_fb.html)
- Add the quxui.swf to your Library Path (Properties->Build Path->Library path). That file is located at /Application/ResearchInMotion/blackberry-tablet-sdk-3.1.0/frameworks/libs/qnx (on Mac).